# The system cannot find the file specified on Production server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, web-config

I have deployed my project to production server. I think my issue with with my database connection, but not sure how I can resolve it. I really appreciate your help.

I do not have this issue on my coding machine.

Here is my connection string in my `web.config`

Here is my connection string on the ISS

> Data
>   Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ClinLab.mdf;Initial
>   Catalog=ClinLab;Integrated Security=True

and this is the error I am getting. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local server does not running at that time.

Go to the services and active the SQL Server(Just right-click on the SQL Server in the Services window and Start.)